How to fetch subentities with SwiftUI @FetchRequest?
Let's say you have defined an entity A in CoreData and then you make it abstract and you give it three subentities B,C and D. You then want to create a list of all these subentities in a View.
How can I fetch all subentities in a single fetch request, ideally like the example below (but not for A just for all subentities of A)
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: A.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \A.a, ascending: false)],
        animation: .default
    ) private var fetchedAs: FetchedResults<A>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(fetchedAs) { pr in
                    Text("foo")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I suspect it might not be possible since when I tried it returned nothing because there  were no A entities saved.
But then im wondering if there is an other way to do this so I don't have to fetch all the subentities individually and then add them together?

You may need a predicate: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-filter-core-data-fetch-requests-using-a-predicate

A predicate is irrelevant for this problem.

By default it does include sub-entities in the fetch results. Check your model is correct.
See the docs here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506366-includessubentities

This does not seem to be the case with the @FetchRequest wrapper. When I try the code above it does not fetch sub-entities.

Did you set parent entity in the model editor?

yes they are set as parent entities.
